# Wireguard issue on home wifi

Tags: debian, vpn, wireless-networking, wireguard

I've recently started to have a few issues with my server (debian) setup, and I'm a bit stumped as to what could have caused it and how to resolve it.

In short: my wireguard setup worked perfectly over the past few months. It now refuses to access the internet when I'm connected to the same network (wifi) as the server itself. It works fine when I'm connected to the cell network though.

Now, I understand that this is a frequent issue, sometimes linked to haipin NAT & so. However, where it gets tricker is that:

1. It worked perfectly with the same config a week ago.
2. I still have 2 other Wireguard endpoints on the same network, no issue there.
   So ultimately, it doesn't seem to be a NAT issue, but rather something specific to this Wireguard config.

The two things that recently changed on this machine are the following:

1. Update from Bullseye to Bookworm. I'm not sure if it is directly correlated, as it stopped working about a week after.
2. Some random Docker change (moved /var/lib/docker/ to another drive).

For additional info on the behaviour: wireguard on the server seems to see the device I'm trying to connect with, but no internet traffic goes through.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you try again without Docker running: `systemctl disable docker.socket docker.service` + reboot (stopping Docker is not enough: it must never have started => reboot)? ( To reenable it: `systemctl enable docker.socket docker.service` )

Comment: Beside, providing the various involved WireGuard and other network configurations could also help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! So, I tried your idea with docker disabled + reboot and indeed, it did resolve the issue while it was disabled (I could connect to the VPN while on the same network as the server). As soon as I restarted docker, the issue reappeared. I did not expect it, considering that WG is not running as a docker container. Any idea on the link between the two things? (I can still copy my config if useful, but it seems to be related to docker more than my WG config, since my other WG endpoints have the same config but not docker and do work).

Comment: Here are links with Q/A with an answer of mine about how Docker disrupts network setups: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572022/linux-bridge-for-virtual-machines-not-forwarding-ip-packets-but-is-forwarding-a , https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network . Find where forwarding is (not) done (anymore), and/or find where a bridge is involved. It can be the first kind of issue (forwarding), the 2nd (bridging) or both. Without your network setup provided in the question, only you can know.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for that! I'll take a bit of time to look into it as I'm not very familiar with those questions, but this is already hugely helpful!